# Write each of these functions as a sum of an even and an odd function..

Tags: functions

Write each of these functions as a sum of an even and an odd function:

1. $f(x) = x^3 + x^6$

I am aware the formula is $\frac12(f(x) + f(-x)) + \frac12(f(x) - f(-x))$
but when subbing in $f(x) = x^3 + x^6$ and $f(-x) = - x^3 + x^6$ I just get my original question $x^6 + x^3$ as the answer. am i going wrong? please can someone explain

Comment: Each of these ... where are they ?

Comment: What is the parity of $x^3$? And $x^6$?

Comment: it's already sum of odd and even function, why do you expect a different result?

Answer (score 1):

The even function is $$f_{even}=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}=x^6$$
The odd function is $$f_{odd}=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=x^3$$